# Function not working in Colorbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, colorbox

On my site http://motiongraphicscollective.com/ i am using colorbox.

When you click on a thumbnail at the home screen i use this script to open my colorbox.

```
 jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'http://motiongraphicscollective.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        data: {
            action: 'myAjax',
            blog_id: blog,
            single_id: single,
        },
        beforeSend:function(data){ // Are not working with dataType:'jsonp'
            $("#"+single+"").find('.project-title').html('<img src="http://motiongraphicscollective.com/wp-content/themes/parallelus-salutation/assets/images/bp-ajax-loader.gif">');
        },
        success: function(data, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest){
            $("#single-content").html('');
            $("#single-content").append(data);
            $(".single_popup").click(); 
        },
        error: function(MLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
            alert(errorThrown);
        }
    });
    $(document).bind('cbox_closed', function(){
        $("#"+single+"").find('.project-title').html(title);
    });
```

As you can see i use Ajax to open my colorbox. The function myAjax will fill the div #single content.

```
function myAjax(){
global $bp;

//get data from our ajax() call
$blog_id = $_POST['blog_id'];
$single_id = $_POST['single_id'];


switch_to_blog($blog_id);
    $post_x = get_post($single_id); 

    //Author Media
    $author = $post_x->post_author;
    $author_firstname =  get_the_author_meta('first_name',$author);
    $author_lastname =  get_the_author_meta('last_name',$author);
    $author_proffesion = get_user_meta( $author,'user_profession', true );

    if(!$author_firstname){
        $author_name =  get_the_author_meta('user_login',$author);
    } else {
        $author_name = $author_firstname . '</br>' . $author_lastname;
    }

     if ( is_user_logged_in() && !bp_is_my_profile() ){ 
        $metion = '<a href="' . bp_get_send_public_message_link() . '" title="Mention this user in a new public message, this will send the user a notification to get their attention.">@ mention</a>';
    }

    $posttext = $post_x->post_content;
    $regular_expression = '~<img [^\>]*\ />~';
    $only_post_text = preg_replace( $regular_expression, '' , $posttext);

    $output =   '<div id="single-video">' . videoBox($single_id) . '</div>';
    $output .=  '<div id="single-middle">'.
                '<div id="single-sidebar">'.
                    '<div id="single-sidebar-inner">'.
                        '<div id="single-avatar">' . bp_core_fetch_avatar( array( 'item_id' => $post_x->post_author, 'type'  => 'full' ) ) . '</div>'.
                    '<div id="single-author"><h3 class="entry-title">' . $author_name . '</h3></div>'.
                    '<div id="single-proffession" class="proffesion">' . $author_proffesion .'</div>'.
                    '<div id="single-follow"></div>'.
                    '<div id="single-portfolio"><a class="btn" href="' . bp_core_get_user_domain($author) . '" title="to author profile">View more projects</a> </div>'.
                    '</div>'.
                '</div>'. 
                    '<div id="single-main">'.
                        '<div class="voting-box">'.
                            '<div id="up">'.
                                wdpv_get_vote_up_ms(true, $blog_id, $single_id) .
                            '</div>'.
                            '<div id="results">'.
                                 wdpv_get_vote_result_ms(false, $blog_id, $single_id). '<span>Thumbs up</span>'.
                            '</div>'.
                        '</div>'.
                        '<div id="single-title">' . $post_x->post_title . '</div>'.
                        '<div id="single-text"><p>' . $only_post_text . '</p></div>'.   
                    '</div>'.
                '</div>';


restore_current_blog();

// Return String
die($output);
```

}

Maybe not the best piece of Ajax but it works.

But not all works, the thumbs up button doesn't work. This is a Wordpress plugin that also works with Ajax. (working example here http://motiongraphicscollective.com/2013/we-think-things-reel-2013/)

How can i make the  thumbs up work within the colorbox?

Comment: Those elements are being added dynamically, and thussly, will require the event to be added to the element i the `success` of the ajax function. If you don't rebind it, then there will never be any request for the currently bound event to fire.

Comment: How can I rebind this to the colorbox?